# Set Property name and Null Value Handling on JsonProperty

Tags: c#, json.net

I have my Property set like this:

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public string TId { get; set; }
```

I also want to be able to make sure that this is camel cased.

```
[JsonProperty("tId")]
public string TId { get; set; }
```

How can I combine these into one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tId", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public string TId { get; set; }
```